# Creating multiple <Route /> components with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a basic React app with several pages and attempting to use react-router-dom. I want to create two paths that render different components:

1. "/"
2. "/books"

```
    import React from "react"
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
    import Home from "./pages/home/Home"
    import Books from "./pages/books/Books"
    
    function App() {
       return (
          <div className="app">
             <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                   <Route path="/add" element={<Books />} />
                </Routes>
             </BrowserRouter>
          </div>
       )
    }
    
    export default App
```

Both imported components are very basic, and follow this structure:

```
import React from "react"

const Books = () => {
   return <div className="books">Books</div>
}

export default Books
```

**EDIT: The above code was the format for most of the components I was using in this app, except the actual Books component I was trying to import which is shown below, and was the cause of the issue!**

```
import React from "react"

export const Books = () => {
   return <div className="books">Books</div>
}
```

If I only include the first route to the Home component, everything works as expected.

When I include the second route to the Books component, the paths show blank HTML pages.

Even if I just include the "import Books from "./pages/books/Books", the first home path does not work and a blank page is displayed.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: As shown above, the component code was incorrect and this was causing the issues.**

Comment: Hello! Can you show us the `Books` component?

Comment: My guess is there's an error attempting to import one of the components, or trying to render it. Please edit the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've better context what the code is doing.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you've shared. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: You just had named and default exports mixed up. Voting to close as "unreproducible or was caused by typo". Cheers.

Comment: What do you prefer to use @davidkonrad ? Genuinely curious as I am just starting out and open minded to learning any stack. Thanks!

Comment: @newportkat That's rather opinionated of davidkonrad, but since they are active in jquery and angular I wouldn't expect them to be very fond of React in the same way that I find jquery and Angular to be very objectionable and complete piles of poo. They (jquery/angular) have a rather orthogonal approach to UI from that of React. To each their own.

Comment: @newportkat Agree. include Vue or similar here as well.  There is no "stack", just more or less propietary company or tech-names. Vue, React, Angular etc.. are just hyped names, you can do a lot, but in the end of the day - have you really improved your code base?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something and it worked!

The Books component that I was trying to import originally looked like this:

```
import React from "react"

export const Books = () => {
   return <div className="books">Books</div>
}
```

But when I changed the component to below, everything worked as expected:

```
import React from "react"

const Books = () => {
   return <div className="books">Books</div>
}

export default Books
```